# Which SHA-1 key should be used when releasing a Xamarin app with a Google login to the Google play store?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-signin

I am releasing my app on the play store using an SHA-1 key to make it able for the user to login via Google provided by Firebase. The key I am using right now is generated by the keytool.exe program using the following command.

```
keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

When using the SHA-1 key generated by the keytool.exe the app works fine on the visual studio emulator and a smartphone connected via usb in both debug and release compile mode.
When the app is published on the google play store using this SHA-1 key the google login does not work anymore.

Which SHA-1 key should be used in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If you have google managing your app signing key (default option now I believe). You will need to use the SHA provided by the PlayConsole for the released version.

- Log into your play console
- Select the relevant App From the Menu
- select Release-->Setup-->App integrity

You want to use the App signing key certificate.[image]

Comment: I used this SHA-1 key and registered it to firebase which I downloaded the googleservices.json file from which incluses this key. After that the app gives me a 12500 status code. Is this something that I could fix in my app or does this require fixing on the firebase/google cloud side?

Comment: `After that the app gives me a 12500 status code.` Could you please post the detail of the error log so that we can help you better?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT It does not give a real error log or exception stack trace, just a failed response with the following content: https://imgur.com/a/pucBM3Z

Comment: I think you can ask Google for better help.